# Java reference to Nested member got lost , trying to avoid singletune

Tags: java, class, memory, nested

Im using server which every request creates stack of its own .
now i have master object which i pass it to each request creation method.
this master object lts call it : GameManager have Nested Map object called GameRooms
and each Room have have Nested Object (Map) called players
something like this :

```
public  class GameManager {
    private final Map<Integer, GameRoom> gameRooms; 
    public GameManager (Map<Integer, GameRoom> _gameRooms)
    {
      gameRooms = _gameRooms;
       create only 1 room 
    gameRooms.put(0,new  GameRoom());
    }
}

public class GameRoom {
      private final Map<Integer, Player> players;
      public GameRoom() 
      {
           players = new HashMap<Integer, Player>();
      }
      public Map<Integer, Player>  getPlayers()
      {
         return players;
      }
}

public int setPlayer(Player _player)
{
    int playerId = _player.getID();
    this.players.put(playerId,_player);   // THIS doesn't keep the player reference
    // //this.players.put(playerId,new Player(_player.getID())); // THIS also doesn't keep the player reference when i do New
}


public class Player {
   private int id;
   public Player (int _id)
   {
       id = _id
   } 
   public int getID() 
   {
      return id
   }
}
```

The server class

```
public class GameServerInitializer extends ChannelInitializer<Channel> {
    private final GameManager gameManager; 
    private int i ;
    public GameServerInitializer(GameManager _gameManager) {
        this.gameManager = _gameManager;
        i = 0;
    }
    //this called on each request 
    public void Request()
    {
          Player p = new Player(i++); 
          //if it the first request it will be 0
          int s = this.gameManager.getGameRooms().get(0).getPlayers().size();
          this.gameManager.getGameRooms().get(0).setPlayer(p);
          //now it is 1 on the first request 
          int s1 = this.gameManager.getGameRooms().get(0).getPlayers().size();

    }

}
```

now from the main when server starting

```
private final Map<Integer, GameRoom> gameRooms = new HashMap<Integer, GameRoom>();
private final GameManager gameManager = new GameManager(gameRooms); 
new GameServerInitializer(gameManager);
```

Now i expecting that the 
this.gameManager.getGameRooms().get(0).getPlayers().size();
will be accumulated each request will add 1 player to the GameRoom 
but this is not happening that size is 0 each request .
this is only with the players , the game rooms Map do keep its size across requests

Comment: Is this the full, syntax-free code?

Comment: no i tried to extract code from the main server it is allot of code ,
i just want to understand the principle